# What are the major differences in building an install profile for Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, installation-profiles

There is a good guide for drupal 7 which explains [how to build a `install profile` for drupal 7](https://drupal.org/node/1022020). I built an install profile using it.

But I want to build an install profile using Drupal 8. What changes do I need to make to my Drupal 7 install profile to make it work for Drupal 8.

PS: I know Drupal 8 is not ready yet but I'm doing this for learning purposes.

Comment: Try Analysing code of https://drupal.org/project/spark distribution for which 8.x version is available...

Comment: This is probably too broad for a single question, creating an install profile start to finish isn't a trivial task. I'd recommend having a go at creating one based off one of the included profiles (or Spark, as @Anil points out), and asking questions about specific problems you encounter. If you're just looking for links to tutorials we can't help, not something we do here

Comment: @Clive: Fair enough! I was also looking for some tutorials/articles/developer videos or any documentation that would help me doing this.

Comment: @claws If you want to change this to be a bit more specific, maybe ask "what are the major differences in building an install profile for Drupal 8?" (and leave out distributions for now), that would be a pretty good question. Our Q+A format works best when questions and answers are self contained, so providing links (tutorials/videos/etc) to back up answers is great, encouraged even, but we need to see the bulk of an answer here to make sure _this_ site remains a good source of info :)

Comment: @Clive: I've edited the question. Now please up vote my question `:P`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from specific code changes like converting the .info file to a .info.yml, the biggest conceptual change is that most of what an install profile will contain are configuration files.

Basically, you can take the configuration directory of in installed site, copy it into the config folder of an install profile and then you're already pretty close to building an install profile that will at the end look like the site.

There will still be a few challenges, for example dependencies between configuration and content. Lee Rowlands (@larowlan) is working on a default content module that allows to import content entities from .yml files too https://github.com/larowlan/default_content, but you can't just stuff all of it into an install profile.

Take a custom block for example. You have a block configuration, which depends on  a custom block content, which in turn depends on a custom block type (bundle of the custom block). I'm guessing the way to solve that will be to split an install profile in a set of modules, that depend on each other.

Comment: The corresponding community documentation to the Drupal 7 instructions cited now exist at How to Write a Drupal 8 Installation Profile - https://www.drupal.org/node/2210443 - which i've edited to add Berdir's important information here and some other useful stuff like https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer if you just want to grab the configuration and don't need to end up with an install profile.